# access specific cell from CSV file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to access specific cell from CSV file table in Matlab.

For example, the CSV file is 4x4, and I want to access cell 1,3

```
1;1;5;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
1;1;1;1
```

Which is 5 in this example

Comment: would you please edit your post, add some code and post your results and mention about errors. Please give example and explain more. get help from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
data = csvread(filename); % whatever your filename is, see doc on csvread
data_of_interest = data(1,3);
```

Comment: Tnx u very much it works. am really happy again and again thank you